# connect oracle using ocilib with hostname specified

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

How to connect Oracle using `OCILIB` with hostname and port number configured.

It by default takes localhost as hostname.

I also checked in the `OCI_ConnectionCreate` function, but it doesn't asks for hostname and port number:

```
 cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate("db", "usr", "pwd", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
```

As my requirement is to connect the oracle server which resides in different server, and my application runs in different server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

question answered in the original topic on OCILIB forum on SF.NET
[Link to topic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orclib/forums/forum/470801/topic/5260257)